# C# it shows null in Console for an else condition, instead of what I want it to display

Tags: c#, if-statement, null, console

So I have this code that will calculate the arithmetic mean. The user has to introduce random numbers, and when the input is "x" the code will stop and calculate the arithmetic mean. The code works fine if I introduce any numbers. However, if the first input is "x" I have to display "0". In the console, I get null ("") instead of 0.

The problem is the 'else' condition, the rest of the code works as expected. I tried to write the condition in different ways and even to put it in another block because I thought it is unreachable, but it is still null. I am not sure what I am missing.

Thank you in advance!

```cs
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            double sum = 0;
            double count = 0;

            while (line != "x")
            {
                double number = Convert.ToInt32(line);
                sum += number;
                count++;
                line = Console.ReadLine();

                if (line == "x")
                {
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        double ma = sum / count;
                        Console.WriteLine((float)ma);
                    }

                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine(0);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Have you tried changing `Console.WriteLine(0)` to `Console.WriteLine('0')` or `Console.WriteLine("0")`?

Comment: Yes, I did that too. The problem persists.

Comment: This means that if the first input is `x`, then the `if` statement is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

If your first line is "X" then the code inside the while loop is not executed at all.
Use a do While loop

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
double sum = 0;
double count = 0;
double number;
double ma;

do
{  
     if (line == "x")
     {
         if (count > 0)
         {
             line = Console.ReadLine();
             ma = sum / count;
             Console.WriteLine((float)ma);
         }

         else {
             Console.WriteLine("0");
         }
     }

     else
     {
         number = Convert.ToInt32(line);
         sum += number;
         count++;
     }
}
while(line != "x")
```

Comment: What will `Convert.ToInt32(line)` do on the first iteration?

Comment: If I write the code this way, it says that the input string is not written in the correct format, at line double number = Convert.ToInt32(line); when i first type x

Comment: I have made the appropriate changes, it was my mistake I had just moved your calculation part without giving it a look. it should work fine now. @withonestar

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  It wasn't clear what to do if user enters something other than 'x' or a number, so I put some error handling which ensures the app doesn't crash.  I added a flag to detect if at least one valid number has been entered.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        double sum = 0;
        double count = 0;
        bool numberHasBeenEntered = false;

        while (line != "x")
        {
            double number;

            //some error handling in case user enters something other than x or a number
            try
            {
                number = Convert.ToInt32(line);
                numberHasBeenEntered = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                break;
            }

            sum += number;
            count++;
            line = Console.ReadLine();

            if (line == "x")
            {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    double ma = sum / count;
                    Console.WriteLine((float)ma);
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(0);
                }
            }
        }

        if (numberHasBeenEntered == false) Console.WriteLine(0);
    }
```